# How to create a tibble from list of tibbles with different number of rows?

Tags: r, list, tibble

I have a list of tibbles that look like this:

```
> head(temp)
$AT
# A tibble: 8,784 × 2
   price_eur datetime           
       <dbl> <dttm>             
 1      50.9 2021-01-01 00:00:00
 2      48.2 2021-01-01 01:00:00
 3      44.7 2021-01-01 02:00:00
 4      42.9 2021-01-01 03:00:00
 5      40.4 2021-01-01 04:00:00
 6      40.2 2021-01-01 05:00:00
 7      39.6 2021-01-01 06:00:00
 8      40.1 2021-01-01 07:00:00
 9      41.3 2021-01-01 08:00:00
10      44.9 2021-01-01 09:00:00
# … with 8,774 more rows

$IE
# A tibble: 7,198 × 2
   price_eur datetime           
       <dbl> <dttm>             
 1      54.0 2021-01-01 01:00:00
 2      53   2021-01-01 02:00:00
 3      51.2 2021-01-01 03:00:00
 4      48.1 2021-01-01 04:00:00
 5      47.3 2021-01-01 05:00:00
 6      47.6 2021-01-01 06:00:00
 7      45.4 2021-01-01 07:00:00
 8      43.4 2021-01-01 08:00:00
 9      47.8 2021-01-01 09:00:00
10      51.8 2021-01-01 10:00:00
# … with 7,188 more rows

$`IT-Calabria`
# A tibble: 8,736 × 2
   price_eur datetime           
       <dbl> <dttm>             
 1      50.9 2021-01-01 00:00:00
 2      48.2 2021-01-01 01:00:00
 3      44.7 2021-01-01 02:00:00
 4      42.9 2021-01-01 03:00:00
 5      40.4 2021-01-01 04:00:00
 6      40.2 2021-01-01 05:00:00
 7      39.6 2021-01-01 06:00:00
 8      40.1 2021-01-01 07:00:00
 9      41.3 2021-01-01 08:00:00
10      41.7 2021-01-01 09:00:00
# … with 8,726 more rows
```

The number of rows is different because there are missing observations, usually one or several days.

Ideally I need a tibble with a single date time index and corresponding columns with NAs when there is missing data and I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a full join by 'datetime'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
reduce(temp, full_join, by = "datetime")
```

---

If we need to `rename` the column 'price_eur' before the join, loop over the `list` with `imap`, `rename` the 'price_eur' to the corresponding list name (`.y`) and do the join within `reduce`

```
imap(temp, ~ .x %>%
              rename(!! .y := price_eur)) %>%
          reduce(full_join, by = 'datetime')
```

Comment: You are great! Sorry for the follow up, but how can I preserve the names to the price columns?

Comment: @QuantumJazz with `tibble/data.frame`, you can't have duplicate column names.  IT will have some suffix `.x`, `.y` etc if those columns are the same.  In the data showed, all the list elements have `price_eur`, so those columns will be made unique in tibble

Comment: Yes, I want to replace them with the corresponding names, i.e. "AT", "IE" and that may be tricky with  "match" (only that comes to mind) because the tibbles might change in future.

Comment: @QuantumJazz try the update

Comment: I only wish to learn some of what you've forgotten. You're great, thanks!